# bibliography in alphabetical order

Tags: sorting

I am using bibliography in the text as bibitem and citing this in the text it is coming correctly. Later I need to have bibiliography in the alphabetical order. How do I do it. I checked  already given answers. Still I have doubt. Please, give me a piece of code which clearly gives the answer. Please, see the LaTeX code below for main file as well as reference file egbib.bib

```
\documentclass[10pt,onecolumn,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{nctt}
%\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

All physical systems are nonlinear in nature. Nonlinear control design technique like backstepping considers the nonlinearity also during design. The 1991 Bode lecture at IEEE CDC, held by Kokotovic was devoted to backstepping and in 1992 kanellakopoulos presented a mathematical toolkit for design of backstepping control laws. During the following year text books by Kristic \cite{kristic} Freeman , Kokotovic and Sepulchre were published.

The discrete-time feedback control techniques such as feedback linearization, backstepping and state dependent riccati equation methods in \cite{ref2}\cite{ref3} and  missile autopilot design was also considered in \cite{ref2} .The application of discrete time backstepping  to  various systems is given in \cite{ref2}\cite{ref4}.

The backstepping control technique is found to have a lot of advantages compared to feedback linearization and gain scheduling. Backstepping does not require exact model for design \cite{ref3}\cite{ref5}.The backstepping technique can solve tracking and regulator problems. It can also provide dead beat control and exact tracking of any desired trajectory in finite time and exploits the flexibility offered by lower order and scalar systems. Backstepping technique takes advantage of useful nonlinearities which help in making the Lyapunov derivative negative definite \cite{kristic}.The discrete backstepping technique has been applied to roll control and sideslip angle control of a reusable launch vehicle. The system is discretized first and then the controller is developed step by step and has given very good tracking and stabilizing performance.

% Include other packages here, before hyperref.

% If you comment hyperref and then uncomment it, you should delete
% egpaper.aux before re-running latex.  (Or just hit 'q' on the first latex
% run, let it finish, and you should be clear).
%\usepackage[breaklinks=true,bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEbib}
\bibliography{egbib}

\end{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%egbib.bib
@misc{kristic,
 author = {M. Kristic and I. Kanellakopoulos and P. Kokotovic},
 title = {Nonlinear and adaptive control design},
 journal  = {John wiely and sons, United States of America},
 year = 1995
}
@misc{ref2,
 author = {P. K. Menon and G. D. Sweriduk and S. S. Vaddi},
 title = {Nonlinear discrete time design methods for missile flight control systems},
 journal  = {AIAA, Guidance navigation and control conference },
 year = 2004
}
@article{ref3,
author = {O. Harkegard},
title = {Flight control design using backstepping},
journal = {Licentiate thesis 875 Linkoping university Linkoping Sweden}, 
year = 2001
}
@article{ref4,
author = {Junguo Lu and Rong Wei and Xiaofan Wang and Zhiquan Wang},
title = {Backstepping Control of discrete time chaotic systems with application to henon system},
journal = {IEEE transaction on ciruits and systems 1},
volume = 48, 
pages = {1359--1363}, 
year = 2001
}
@article{ref5,
author = {Johan Dahlgren},
title = {Robust nonlinear control design for missile using backstepping},
journal = {}, 
year = 2002
}
@article{ref6,
author = {Diagoro Ito and Jennifer Georgie and John Valasek and Donald T. Ward},
title = {Reentry vehicle flight controls design guidelines Dynamic inversion},
journal = {Report NASA center for aerospace information}, 
year = 2002
}
@article{ref8,
author = {N.Naveen and S.Geetha and S.Ushakumari},
title = {Backstepping control technique applied to discrete time sytem},
journal = {National Conference on Technological Trends}, 
year = 2013
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

my requirement is all bibiliographic items should come in the text and it should be in alphabetical order.
thank you
geetha

Comment: I'm not familiar with the bibtex style file `IEEEbib.bst`. IEEE's "standard" style file, which is called `IEEEtran.bst`, does *not* sort the entries alphabetically, i.e., the entries are listed by order of citation appearance. If you want alphabetical sorting, use either `IEEEtranS.bst` or `IEEEtranSN.bst`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, are you giving us a free hand by just demanding alphabetical sorting? ;-) You can use `natbib`, replace all `\cite` with `\citet` (or `\citep` if you like) and put this for example

```
\bibliographystyle{apa}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,onecolumn,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[authoryear,sort]{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{filecontents*}{egbib.bib}
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%egbib.bib
@misc{kristic,
 author = {M. Kristic and I. Kanellakopoulos and P. Kokotovic},
 title = {Nonlinear and adaptive control design},
 journal  = {John wiely and sons, United States of America},
 year = 1995
}
@misc{ref2,
 author = {P. K. Menon and G. D. Sweriduk and S. S. Vaddi},
 title = {Nonlinear discrete time design methods for missile flight control systems},
 journal  = {AIAA, Guidance navigation and control conference },
 year = 2004
}
@article{ref3,
author = {O. Harkegard},
title = {Flight control design using backstepping},
journal = {Licentiate thesis 875 Linkoping university Linkoping Sweden},
year = 2001
}
@article{ref4,
author = {Junguo Lu and Rong Wei and Xiaofan Wang and Zhiquan Wang},
title = {Backstepping Control of discrete time chaotic systems with application to henon system},
journal = {IEEE transaction on ciruits and systems 1},
volume = 48,
pages = {1359--1363},
year = 2001
}
@article{ref5,
author = {Johan Dahlgren},
title = {Robust nonlinear control design for missile using backstepping},
journal = {},
year = 2002
}
@article{ref6,
author = {Diagoro Ito and Jennifer Georgie and John Valasek and Donald T. Ward},
title = {Reentry vehicle flight controls design guidelines Dynamic inversion},
journal = {Report NASA center for aerospace information},
year = 2002
}
@article{ref8,
author = {N.Naveen and S.Geetha and S.Ushakumari},
title = {Backstepping control technique applied to discrete time sytem},
journal = {National Conference on Technological Trends},
year = 2013
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

All physical systems are nonlinear in nature. Nonlinear control design technique like backstepping considers the nonlinearity also during design. The 1991 Bode lecture at IEEE CDC, held by Kokotovic was devoted to backstepping and in 1992 kanellakopoulos presented a mathematical toolkit for design of backstepping control laws. During the following year text books by Kristic \citet{kristic} Freeman , Kokotovic and Sepulchre were published.

The discrete-time feedback control techniques such as feedback linearization, backstepping and state dependent riccati equation methods in \citet{ref2}\citet{ref3} and  missile autopilot design was also considered in \citet{ref2} .The application of discrete time backstepping  to  various systems is given in \citet{ref2}\citet{ref4}.

The backstepping control technique is found to have a lot of advantages compared to feedback linearization and gain scheduling. Backstepping does not require exact model for design \citet{ref3}\citet{ref5}.The backstepping technique can solve tracking and regulator problems. It can also provide dead beat control and exact tracking of any desired trajectory in finite time and exploits the flexibility offered by lower order and scalar systems. Backstepping technique takes advantage of useful nonlinearities which help in making the Lyapunov derivative negative definite \citet{kristic}.The discrete backstepping technique has been applied to roll control and sideslip angle control of a reusable launch vehicle. The system is discretized first and then the controller is developed step by step and has given very good tracking and stabilizing performance.

% Include other packages here, before hyperref.

% If you comment hyperref and then uncomment it, you should delete
% egpaper.aux before re-running latex.  (Or just hit 'q' on the first latex
% run, let it finish, and you should be clear).
%\usepackage[breaklinks=true,bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{apa}
\bibliography{egbib}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure the OP meant to indicate that any arbitrary bibliography style that performs alphabetical sorting of the entries will do.

Comment: @mico: The OP does not mention that it is an IEEE article (except the use of some .bst that has IEEE in it). The document class is article.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you look for bibtex styles on the net. There are several sites which list different bibtex styles that mark and order the items differently.

It is of course possible to design your own style, but usually one of the bibliographystyles from the internet match your requirements.

Comment: Suggesting to go "look for bibtex styles on the net" doesn't narrow the search down much, does it? You may want, at the very least, provide a couple of suggestions for bibliography styles that do order the references alphabetically by authors' surnames.

Comment: It's true, my answer was too short, but I had the impression that the questioner was unaware of the fact that the style determines the sorting.